# Existence of 3 natural numbers that divide each other when squared and have 1 taken away from them

Tags: number-theory, natural-numbers

Does there exist natural numbers, $a,b,c > 1$, such that;

$a^2 - 1$ is divisible by $b$ and $c$,
$b^2 - 1$ is divisible by $a$ and $c$ and
$c^2 - 1$ is divisible by $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. This is a nice question. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Any results from searching for examples?

Comment: I've noticed that $a^2 -1 = (a-1)(a+1)$ and hence must have b or c divide either a-1 or a+1. However havent figured out any further than that. I also tested some numbers but couldnt find any that fit

Comment: Unless $b,c$ are prime it is not true that $b,c$ must divide one of $a+1,a-1$.

Comment: If  you think that the first part of the problem statement implies that $b$ and $c$ must each divide $a-1$ or $a+1$, and similarly for the other two parts, I think you will quickly find that it can't work that way.

Comment: The only triples with five out of six; and all three below 1000, are: $(3,4,5),(3,7,8),(8,21,55),(24,115,551),(15,56,209)$

Comment: Clearly no two numbers can be the same and exactly one must be even.

Comment: Those triples include $(n^2-1,n^3-2n,n^4-3n^2+1)$

Comment: In that case five remainders are 0 and the sixth remainder is $n^2-1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No such numbers exist.

First, observe that $a,b,c$ are pairwise coprime:  For example, since $a$ divides $b^2-1$, any prime $p$ that divides $a$ also divides $b^2 - 1$; hence $p$ does not divide $b^2$ and also does not divide $b$.  Thus $a$ and $b$ are coprime; and likewise for the other pairs.

Since $b,c$ are coprime and each divide $a^2 - 1$, so does their product $bc$.  Since all the quantities are positive, that implies $bc \le a^2 - 1 \lt a^2$.  So we have three strict inequalities:
$$
\begin{align}
bc &\lt a^2\\
ac &\lt b^2\\
ab &\lt c^2
\end{align}
$$ 
Multiplying these inequalities together yields
$$
a^2 b^2 c^2 \lt a^2 b^2 c^2
$$
which is impossible.